# Erro de sintaxe - parse_url(getenv("CLEARDB_DATABASE_URL"));

Tags: php

Estou tentando conectar o banco de uma aplicação em PHP no `herokuapp` usando o ClearDB e simplesmente recebo um erro de sintaxe na linha 6 do código e eu não sei exatamente o porquê disso. A aplicação não funciona, somente se eu colocar *host*, *senha* e *username* diretamente, o que não é possível pois a aplicação se encontra no `git` também.

Segue o código:

```
    <?php

class Database {

    private $url = parse_url(getenv("CLEARDB_DATABASE_URL"));
    private $host = $url["host"];
    private $db_name = substr($url["path"], 1);
    private $username = $url["user"];
    private $password = $url["pass"];
    public $conn;

    public function getConnection() { 

            $this->conn = null;

            try {
                $this->conn = new PDO("mysql:host=" . $this->host . ";dbname=" . $this->db_name, $this->username, $this->password);
            } catch (PDOException $exception) {
                echo "Connection error: " . $exception->getMessage();
            }

            return $this->conn;
    }     
}

?>
```

Comment: Qual erro aparece?

Comment: Esse aqui "Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '(', expecting ',' or ';' on line 6" ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Propriedades de objetos devem ser instancias com valores simples definidos em tempo de compilação e não determinados em 'tempo de execução' como chamadas de funções e outros tipos de expressões.

```
class Database {
   private $url = parse_url(getenv("CLEARDB_DATABASE_URL"));
```

Jogue essa inicialização no construtor da classe:

```
public function __construct(){
    $this->url =  parse_url(getenv("CLEARDB_DATABASE_URL"));
    $this->host = $this->url["host"];
    $this->db_name = substr($this->url["path"], 1);
    $this->username = $this->url["user"];
    $this->password = $this->url["pass"];
}
```

[Propriedade - Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.properties.php)

Comment: hmmmmmm...entendi, porém, agora recebo o seguinte erro: " Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$url' (T_VARIABLE) " ...

Comment: @LucasdeAlbuquerque isso se aplica aos demais também, fiz uma edição na resposta.

Comment: HMmmmmm...isso mesmo, perfeito! Agora rodou liso...muito obrigado pela ajuda...! Uma coisa tão simples e eu quebrando a cabeça... --'